# How to write create random username and password selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

how to i can write issue create random username password and select dropdown
with selenium python ?

My code select dropdown:

```
self.find_element_by_xpath(randint(0, len("//*[@id='shop_delivery_delivery_id']") + 1))
```

and i have to error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> self.find_element_by_xpath(randint(0, len("//*[@id='shop_delivery_delivery_id']") + 1))
> AttributeError: type object 'CreateDeliveryMode' has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'
> ```

I do not know why
Please tell me how to write. Thank you 
Ps.I'm fairly new to python and selenium

Comment: Could you add html with username and password fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can take help from the below given code snippet.

```
getRandomString (var length) {

    var string = '';
    var i=0;

    var letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' //Include numbers if you want

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) 
           {
                string += letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length));
            }

   return string;
}
```

You can use it by calling the function like

```
getRandomString(5) and it will return "gfsxs"
```

Everytime you call this function it will return a random string.